# Covert numpy.ndarray to a list

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to convert this numpy.ndarray to a list

```
[[105.53518731]
 [106.45317529]
 [107.37373843]
 [108.00632646]
 [108.56373502]
 [109.28813113]
 [109.75593207]
 [110.57458371]
 [111.47960639]]
```

I'm using this function to convert it.

```
conver = conver.tolist()
```

the output is this, I'm not sure whether it's a list and if so, can I access its elements by doing cover[0] , etc

```
[[105.5351873125], [106.45317529411764], [107.37373843478261], [108.00632645652173], [108.56373502040816], [109.28813113157895], [109.75593206666666], [110.57458370833334], [111.47960639393939]]
```

finally, after I convert it to a list, I try to multiply the list members by 1.05 and get this error!

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: That's a list. It looks exactly how I would expect the result to look.

Comment: then what's the difference between [[105.5351873125], [106.45317529411764] and [105.5351873125,106.45317529411764]
 and why i'm getting the error ?

Comment: [] this means a list. However, this one here means a list that has different lists inside itself [ [], [], [] ]

Comment: What were you expecting, and what actually happened? Even if this case that's not a problem, please provide some expected output anyways.

Answer (score 3):

You start with a 2d array, with shape (n,1), like this:

```
In [342]: arr = np.random.rand(5,1)*100                                                                
In [343]: arr                                                                                          
Out[343]: 
array([[95.39049043],
       [19.09502087],
       [85.45215423],
       [94.77657561],
       [32.7869103 ]])
```

tolist produces a list - but it contains lists; each [] layer denotes a list.  Notice that the [] nesting matches the array's:

```
In [344]: arr.tolist()                                                                                 
Out[344]: 
[[95.39049043424225],
 [19.095020872584335],
 [85.4521542296349],
 [94.77657561477125],
 [32.786910295446425]]
```

To get a number you have to index through each list layer:

```
In [345]: arr.tolist()[0]                                                                              
Out[345]: [95.39049043424225]
In [346]: arr.tolist()[0][0]                                                                           
Out[346]: 95.39049043424225
In [347]: arr.tolist()[0][0]*1.05                                                                      
Out[347]: 100.16001495595437
```

If you first turn the array into a 1d one, the list indexing is simpler:

```
In [348]: arr.ravel()                                                                                  
Out[348]: array([95.39049043, 19.09502087, 85.45215423, 94.77657561, 32.7869103 ])
In [349]: arr.ravel().tolist()                                                                         
Out[349]: 
[95.39049043424225,
 19.095020872584335,
 85.4521542296349,
 94.77657561477125,
 32.786910295446425]
In [350]: arr.ravel().tolist()[0]                                                                      
Out[350]: 95.39049043424225
```

But if your primary goal is to multiply the elements, doing with the array is simpler:

```
In [351]: arr * 1.05                                                                                   
Out[351]: 
array([[100.16001496],
       [ 20.04977192],
       [ 89.72476194],
       [ 99.5154044 ],
       [ 34.42625581]])
```

You can access elements of the array with:

```
In [352]: arr[0,0]                                                                                     
Out[352]: 95.39049043424225
```

But if you do need to iterate, the `tolist()` option is good to know.  Iterating on lists is usually faster than iterating on an array.  With an array you should try to use the fast whole-array methods.

Answer (score 0):

you convert to list of list, so you could not broadcast.

```
import numpy as np
x = [[105.53518731],
 [106.45317529],
 [107.37373843],
 [108.00632646],
 [108.56373502],
 [109.28813113],
 [109.75593207],
 [110.57458371],
 [111.47960639],]
x = np.hstack(x)
x * 1.05

array([110.81194668, 111.77583405, 112.74242535, 113.40664278,
       113.99192177, 114.75253769, 115.24372867, 116.1033129 ,
       117.05358671])
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's a list, you can check the type of a variable:

```
type(a)
```

to multiply each element with `1.05` then run the code below:

```
x = [float(i[0]) * 1.05 for i in a]
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

a = [[105.53518731],
 [106.45317529],
 [107.37373843],
 [108.00632646],
 [108.56373502],
 [109.28813113],
 [109.75593207],
 [110.57458371],
 [111.47960639]]

b = [elem[0] for elem in a]
b = np.array(b)

print(b*1.05)
```